# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS internal Microphone doesn't work

Tags: drivers, sound, lts

I have Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on my Intel laptop. The microphone was working fine until it suddenly stopped working for no reason. I'm using OBS Studio all the time.

Here's some debug:

```
morad@Zelakolase:~$ aplay -l && arecord -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3227 Analog [ALC3227 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3227 Analog [ALC3227 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

And

```
morad@Zelakolase:~$ lspci -vvv
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 129
    Region 0: Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Region 2: Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 4: I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at b1220000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device

00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 11
    Region 0: Memory at b1232000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 124
    Region 0: Memory at b1210000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin C routed to IRQ 18
    Region 0: Memory at b1233000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 127
    Region 0: Memory at b1234000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 126
    Region 0: Memory at b1230000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Region 1: Memory at b1237000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Region 2: I/O ports at 4080 [size=8]
    Region 3: I/O ports at 4088 [size=4]
    Region 4: I/O ports at 4060 [size=32]
    Region 5: Memory at b1235000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 122
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: b1100000-b11fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000fff00000-00000000000fffff [disabled]
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA- VGA- VGA16- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 123
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000f000-00000fff [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: b1000000-b10fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000fff00000-00000000000fffff [disabled]
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA- VGA- VGA16- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0

00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP PMC
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Region 0: Memory at b122c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21) (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 32, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 130
    Region 0: Memory at b1228000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Region 4: Memory at b1200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at b1236000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Region 4: I/O ports at 4040 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    DeviceName: Hanksville Gbe Lan Connection
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at b1104000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Region 4: Memory at b1100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 128
    Region 0: Memory at b1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

And

```
morad@Zelakolase:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
uvcvideo               98304  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       57344  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              241664  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
mc                     57344  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
rfcomm                 81920  4
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxdrv               516096  2 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
ccm                    20480  3
cmac                   16384  6
algif_hash             16384  3
algif_skcipher         16384  3
af_alg                 28672  14 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
bnep                   24576  2
mei_hdcp               24576  0
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
btusb                  57344  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
coretemp               20480  0
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
snd_hda_codec_realtek   131072  1
btintel                28672  1 btusb
kvm_intel             286720  0
bluetooth             581632  31 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
iwlmvm                393216  0
kvm                   712704  1 kvm_intel
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
ecc                    32768  1 ecdh_generic
mac80211              905216  1 iwlmvm
i915                 2195456  19
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           372736  11
snd_hda_intel          53248  3
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  5 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  1 snd_hda_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_hda_codec         139264  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
drm_kms_helper        217088  1 i915
snd_hda_core           94208  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
cec                    53248  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
snd_pcm               114688  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
rc_core                57344  1 cec
iwlwifi               352256  1 iwlmvm
rapl                   20480  0
intel_cstate           20480  0
intel_xhci_usb_role_switch    16384  0
roles                  16384  1 intel_xhci_usb_role_switch
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
cfg80211              778240  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
joydev                 24576  0
input_leds             16384  0
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
serio_raw              20480  0
mei_me                 40960  1
snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
ee1004                 20480  0
kxcjk_1013             28672  0
processor_thermal_device    24576  0
snd                    94208  17 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
intel_rapl_common      28672  2 intel_rapl_msr,processor_thermal_device
mei                   106496  3 mei_hdcp,mei_me
industrialio_triggered_buffer    16384  1 kxcjk_1013
kfifo_buf              16384  1 industrialio_triggered_buffer
hp_wmi                 16384  0
intel_vbtn             20480  0
int340x_thermal_zone    20480  1 processor_thermal_device
cm32181                16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
intel_soc_dts_iosf     20480  1 processor_thermal_device
sparse_keymap          16384  2 hp_wmi,intel_vbtn
soundcore              16384  1 snd
industrialio           77824  4 industrialio_triggered_buffer,cm32181,kfifo_buf,kxcjk_1013
int3400_thermal        20480  0
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
intel_pch_thermal      20480  0
hp_wireless            16384  0
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    20480  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
acpi_pad              184320  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
parport_pc             45056  0
drm                   552960  8 drm_kms_helper,i915
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                65536  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               49152  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
i2c_i801               32768  0
psmouse               155648  0
ahci                   40960  2
i2c_smbus              20480  1 i2c_i801
libahci                36864  1 ahci
r8169                  77824  0
realtek                24576  1
xhci_pci               20480  0
xhci_pci_renesas       20480  1 xhci_pci
wmi                    32768  3 hp_wmi,intel_wmi_thunderbolt,wmi_bmof
video                  49152  1 i915
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Is it possible there were some upgrades between when it worked and now it does not? If so you may have had a kernel update from 5.4 to 5.8. If this is the case when you boot choose adv and load the 5.4 kernel and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @David I'm on Linux version 5.8.0-45-generic . I'll try.

Comment: That is the 5.8 kernel try the 5.4 and see if it fixes it.

Comment: @David Hey mate. Got into another problem!

Comment: @David Grub doesn't show up

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time This will help

Comment: @David Doesn't work. I think kernel 5.4 isn't the problem here?